# How to display data result from database in C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, web, ms-access

I am trying to make a website in C# and .accdb database using Visual Studio 2010
my .accdb database has username and score and I want to display the user that has credit more than 0 to the Default.aspx

So I created a button and a textbox.

```
<div>
<asp:Button ID="CreditSearch" runat="server" Text="Credit" onclick="btnCreditSearch_Click"  />
 </div>
```

and the function for btnCreditSearch_Click is:

```
protected void btnCreditSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreditSearch();
}

private void CreditSearch()
{
    string users;
    users = Process.UserCreditSearch();
    string A = users.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text(A);
}
```

and my Process.UserCreditSearch() is:

```
   public static string UserCreditSearch()
{
    string query = "SELECT srusername FROM usertb WHERE credit > 0 ";
    return query;

}
```

but then it is not working.  for the credit search function, it says "Non invocable member' System.UI.Webcontrol.TextBox.Text' can not be use like a method

I hope somebody knows what I done wrong and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Text is a Property

```
TextBox1.Text= A;
```

Comment: thanks now I changed to TextBox1.Text= A;
but now the textbox displayed "SELECT srusername FROM usertb WHERE credit > 0 " but what I want is the users that has credits larger than 0

Is there any problem of the code that causing this?

Comment: string query = "SELECT srusername FROM usertb WHERE credit > 0 ";
//this is wrong because select statement return a table you are assigning it to a string and  there must be a connection handling class

Comment: @Ric: Where is your connection class?

Comment: @Ric: what do you do if you get back multiple users with `credit > 0` ??